# Client-side vs. server-side authorization in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authorization, client-side, server-side, route-provider

I'm working on this application where the user is supposed to answer a bunch of questions.

What I want to do is protect the page that has the JSON of the question Objects, which also contains sensitive information, such as the answer(s) to the questions.

What I'm trying to do is restrict access to that page for non-admin users on the client-side (they should not be able to type and go to that URL and see the JSON on that page, they should get a 403), while allowing HTTP GET requests from non-admin users on the server-side, so I can get the questions for them to answer.

This is what I have on the client-side:

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/questions', {
        resolve: checkRoleForRoute.admin
    })
```

And this is what I have on the server-side:

```
    application.get('/questions', questions.getQuestions);
```

Both work well for separate routes, but once the route is the same, the server-side code is always executed, while the client-side code isn't. Therefore, any user that is not an admin is able to see the plain JSON when they access the URL, which is not desirable.
Any ideas on why is this happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should add some security check on server side, before providing the JSON data back, i.e. the server should check if the data can be provided to the requesting user.

Moreover, in my opinion, the route is hackable in client-side too.
In fact, using browser's dev tool one can change or skip the 'resolve' field, if he's smart enough.